What does Ken mean in episode one as he enters tunnel by "shy boy"?
In episode 1 of Dan Da Dan, Ken hesitantly enters the tunnel somewhat fearful.  He refers to himself aloud a couple of times as "shy boy", in context maybe to psyche himself up.  It's quite likely that this relates to some sort of Japanese cultural reference.  What is it?

I guess being shy simply makes him hide himself. If this does not make sense, it could be a translation gap between shy and the Japanese 恥ずかしがりや(≒ shy boy).

@sundowner Thank you for commenting.  I do wonder what extra contextual meaning Japanese people draw from that phrase in that context.  I guess it could be like you say, striving to become shy and invisible.

I looked up 対人恐怖 (wikipedia:en), which is (arguably) an extreme case of 恥ずかしがや. Actually it mentions cultural aspect of the symptom. So yeah, there could be a difference around the term.

I haven't watched the anime, but if I came across this in the "wild", I'd probably interpret it himself trying to hype himself up, and probably(?) doesn't have anything to do with Japan's culture. Sometimes in media, people repeat insults that other people tell them to make themselves angry in an attempt to gather the courage required for an action.

It's the the chorus of TOO SHY SHY BOY!, a 1992 song by Alisa Mizuki.
The song's lyrics about romantic anxiety and shyness might be reflective of Okarun's current frame of mind, considering he's trying to become friends with Ayase.
Another meaning may be that it highlights his outdated tastes. Note that in the same scene we see that he uses a flip phone.

Excellent -- Thank you.  I just re-watched that segment of episode 1, and now I can hear that he even times his (speaking) cadence to that of the song.
